# NextJs 13 Link props “href” and “as”

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, next.js13

I try create link to page with certain id like “about/[id]” and want to show url in browser only with title of subject but also I need to request info by “id”
use next app router:

```
<Link href={`about/${id}`} as={`about/${title}`}>
 {`read about ${title}`
</Link>
```

But as a result in browser  anchor tag has attribute href equals to “as” prop
In child component `props.params.id === title`. So I assume that “as” is the same prop “href”.
What is the possible way to mask url in next13 app router?